# Огромный размер exe после компилирования

Tags: python, qt, gui, exe, pyinstaller

**Начинающий в программировании.** 
Написал простенький gui калькулятор на Qt Designer, скомпилировал с помощью pyinstaller с флагом -F и получил экзешник НА 30 МБ. Это явно не нормально, почему размер такой огромный и как его уменьшить? Помогите. 
*Если что-то не так оформил, пишите, я тут в первый раз задаю вопрос.*
Вот код:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from sys import argv, exit 

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(540, 60)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(540, 60))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(540, 60))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"font-size: 23px;\n"
"}\n"
"QComboBox {\n"
"font-size: 20px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit {\n"
"font-size: 20px;\n"
"}")
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit_first = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_first.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 151, 41))
        self.lineEdit_first.setObjectName("lineEdit_first")
        self.lineEdit_second = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_second.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 10, 151, 41))
        self.lineEdit_second.setObjectName("lineEdit_second")
        self.pushButton_equally = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_equally.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 31, 41))
        self.pushButton_equally.setObjectName("pushButton_equally")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 41, 41))
        self.comboBox.setEditable(False)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.lineEdit_answer = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_answer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 10, 151, 41))
        self.lineEdit_answer.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_answer.setFrame(True)
        self.lineEdit_answer.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_answer.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_answer.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.lineEdit_answer.setObjectName("lineEdit_answer")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор", None, -1))
        self.pushButton_equally.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "=", None, -1))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "+", None, -1))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "-", None, -1))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "÷", None, -1))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "×", None, -1))

        self.pushButton_equally.clicked.connect(equally)

def equally():
    try:
        first = float(ui.lineEdit_first.text())
        second = float(ui.lineEdit_second.text())
        act = str(ui.comboBox.currentText())
        if act == "+":
            a = first + second
            ui.lineEdit_answer.setText(format(a, '.10g'))
        elif act == "-":
            a = first - second
            ui.lineEdit_answer.setText(format(a, '.10g'))
        elif act == "÷":
            a = first / second
            ui.lineEdit_answer.setText(format(a, '.10g'))
        elif act == "×":
            a = first * second
            ui.lineEdit_answer.setText(format(a, '.10g'))
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Код о котором речь идет в сообщение добавьте для начала

Comment: Долго не мог разобраться, но добавил.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe  и здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629486/how-can-i-create-the-minimum-size-executable-with-pyinstaller

Comment: Хм, ну как я понял нужная какая-то виртуальная среда и т.п. А нет какого-то более практичного способа компиляции py в exe? Допустим не pyinstaller, а что-то другое.